# API Design for Service Layer

Tags: java, api, oop, design-patterns

I am a novice programmer learning how to design API for my module. I thought of 2 types of service class to provide a API for other classes to use.

First example handles the logic by parameters, the second example handles by object way.

Which is a better approach / design for me to provide business methods for other classes to use?

As a general rule of thumb which should I use?

Example 1 - Service A

```
public class ServiceA {

    private SampleDAO dao =  new SampleDAO();
    private static final String DRAFT_STATUS = "DRAFT";
    private static final String APPROVED_STATUS = "APPROVED";
    private static final String SUBMITTED_STATUS = "SUBMITTED";


    public boolean isDocumentApprove(String documentId) {
        Document doc = getDocument(documentId);

        return (APPROVED_STATUS.equals(doc.getStatus()));
    }

    public boolean isDocumentDraft(String documentId) {
        Document doc = getDocument(documentId);

        return (DRAFT_STATUS.equals(doc.getStatus()));
    }

    public boolean isDocumentSubmited(String documentId) {
        Document doc = getDocument(documentId);

        return (SUBMITTED_STATUS.equals(doc.getStatus()));
    }


    private Document getDocument(String documentId) {
        return (dao.getByDocumentId(documentId));
    }
}
```

Example 2 - Service B

```
public class ServiceB {

    private SampleDAO dao =  new SampleDAO();
    private static final String DRAFT_STATUS = "DRAFT";
    private static final String APPROVED_STATUS = "APPROVED";
    private static final String SUBMITTED_STATUS = "SUBMITTED";


    public Document getDocument(String documentId) {
        return (dao.getByDocumentId(documentId));
    }

    public boolean isDocumentApprove(Document doc) {    
        return (APPROVED_STATUS.equals(doc.getStatus()));
    }

    public boolean isDocumentDraft(Document doc) {
        return (DRAFT_STATUS.equals(doc.getStatus()));
    }

    public boolean isDocumentSubmited(Document doc) {   
        return (SUBMITTED_STATUS.equals(doc.getStatus()));
    }

}
```

Comment: I fail to see the point of the second example. If the caller already has an instance of Document, why would it call a service to get the status of the document? Why not simply do `doc.isApproved()`?

Comment: The caller will retrieve the document and pass it to the appropriate methods to check the status of the document etc.

Comment: I understand that. But it's unnecessarily complex. If you have a document, get its status directly by calling a method on the document rather than calling an additional method on the service.

Comment: won't it be very repetitive for all other classes to repeat the same checks?

Comment: Why would it be too repetitive to always call `doc.isApproved()`, rather than `service.isApproved(doc)`?

Comment: you might look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3885675/217324, it might clarify the point of having a service layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to choose, i would pick the the second example, because it contains less code duplication. In the first one, there is the same `Document doc = getDocument(documentId);` statement in every method. So, here the general principle is "don't repeat yourself".

Furthermore, in the first version you can pass any garbage as a string to the methods. Although you can pass null in the second version too, but it is easier to check for null than for invalid ids.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the goal of your API.

Does the caller *always* have a `DocumentID` and *never* a `Document` instance?

- ServiceA is the way to go (abstract the `Document` instance and only return a status).

Does the caller *sometimes* have a `DocumentID` and *sometimes* a `Document` instance?

- ServiceB is the way to go as you offer the caller the ability to either get a document or get the status.
- In this case you would be better off modifying your `Document` class to include a `getStatus()` method.  That way if the caller has a `Document` instance they can call `document.getStatus()` instead of calling your service.