# When a Spring MVC Controller seems to have too much logic

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have a question about where is the borderline between including some kind of code in `Controller` and `Service`. I think that i've included bussiness logic in the wrong place. Let me show you an example that i want to refactor, this is part of a handler method which receives `lists` `(currentRoles, pendingOfAuthRoles..etc)` to update user roles:

```
    //Insert new roles
    List<Role> storedRoles = userService.getRoles(username);
    List<Role> newAcceptanceRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    for(Role role : currentRoles){
        if(!storedRoles.contains(role)){
            if(roleService.getPolicies(role.getRoleName()).size()>0){
                userService.insertRole(username, role.getRoleName(), true, false);
                newAcceptanceRoles.add(role);
            }else{
                userService.insertRole(username, role.getRoleName(), true, true);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!newAcceptanceRoles.isEmpty())
        mailService.sendRoleAcceptanceEmail(ControllerUtils.getBaseURL(httpServletRequest), username, newAcceptanceRoles.toString(), userService.getUserByUsername(username).getEmail());
```

In this part of the code, i insert the new relations between the user and roles. Some roles needs admin authorization, so that, the `USER_ROLE` table has a flag in order not to include roles with `authorized=0` as a current user roles through a view.

If the role is not stored as a user role i insert it by setting the auth flag to `false`, furthermore if the role needs authorization an email is sent to the admin.

Do I need a service method like...

`updateUserRoles(currentRoles, pendingOfAuth, pendingOfAccept)`

and do this kind of work in the service or not?

Comment: yes, your services are too fine-grained, they're essentially daos. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3885675/217324. just be careful about sending email (because it is obviously not transactional).

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. Does the mailService would be a Component? i mean.. are  services only for transactional operations? The MailService has Autowired services.

Comment: Just saying be careful. Say you send an email in your service method, then when spring tries to commit the transaction rolls back. Your email is sent already -- if your email is supposed to go only if the transaction succeeds then you have a problem.