# Handle multiple Users JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller, software-design

I need an advice. I'm creating a web app and I should handle multiple type of user.
An user is a Customer and another one is an Admin. How can I map this in JPA config?
Should I use inheritance?

E.g.

```
Customer extends User [...]
```

*EDIT*

If I take Customer, this "is an" User, as well as, Admin "is an" User. So if I consider "is an" as relationship, Customer table has fields, like address, telephone, etc..., that Admin Table doesn't need. Consequentily, Customer has relationships with other table that they are different about Admin. How could I map this with JPA?

Thanks

Comment: No, don’t use inheritance.  Use roles.

Comment: @NathanHughes Yeah, I've forgotten a particular. I'm already using roles. I would split the logic of every  User Entity. Because I don't need to save all fields of a customer for an admin.

Comment: It sounds like the code for that should be in different services. See [my answer about what should be in a controller vs what should be in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885783/217324).

Comment: In my opinion, It isn't an issue about controller and service. My "sub-users" have several relationship with other tables, so I would keep this "logic" on Entities side.

Comment: Maybe you could add few concrete example entities and logic - minimal - to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: Maybe the word "logic" has confused.
If I take Customer, this "is an" User, as well as, Admin "is an" User. So if consider "is an" as relationship. Customer table has fields, like address, telephone, etc..., that Admin Table doesn't need. Consequentily, Customer has relationships with other table that they are different about Admin. How could I map this with JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I followed this guide:
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

So, I used `strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED` for my purpose.